# How to use the hide methods in API?

Tags: android, bluetooth, overriding

I have seen some hide methods in

```
/** @hide */
public void setDiscoverableTimeout(int timeout) {
    if (getState() != STATE_ON) return;
    try {
        mService.setDiscoverableTimeout(timeout);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {Log.e(TAG, "", e);}
}
```

I want to use the above method but still not aware that how can I use this method in my program so that my app should be always in discoverable mode?

Comment: Maybe this blog is helpful:
[http://blog.codetastrophe.com/2008/12/accessing-hidden-system-service-apis-in.html](http://blog.codetastrophe.com/2008/12/accessing-hidden-system-service-apis-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use reflections, i have been using it. The only flip side is it may be google doesn't provide any guarantee for it.

Comment: how to use it and Naresh I am unable to solve this problem, I want my android bluetooth discovery on all the time, yar what should I do ?

Comment: Class c = Class.forName(android.bluetooth.BluetoothClass.Service);
  Method method = c.getMethodByName("Whatever method name u want");
  method.invoke(mService, args..) above is a sample code

Comment: Let me try Naresh, can you help me a bit more dear, it is my first Android Project and want a bit help :-(